# class wise Tensorflow object detection count

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

Can we count detected objects  in Tensorflow object detection API class wise?  Say you have two classes car and bicyle, I would like to count  each object class wise ex; ,Carcount:5 bicycle count:3.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to do the following

```
boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
(boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run([boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

final_score = np.squeeze(scores)    
car_count = 0

for i in range(100):
    if final_score[i] > 0.5:
        detected_class = int(classes[0][i])
        if detected_class == 1:
            car_count += 1
```

Here, the class name and the number are mapped according to the values that you specified in your `label_map.pbtxt` file. I hope this helps you out. Let me know in case you face any issues

Comment: I am still not able to get the count of each classes detected.
I used the above method.

Comment: @Bhawna_priya, could you please mention the exact error or problem you're facing?